# Alternatives to National Express in the UK

Tags: uk, buses

I would prefer not to use National Express. Conditions on coaches can be awful, in my experience. I wish we had something like [Polskibus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PolskiBus) in the UK.

Are there any alternatives? I mainly use them to get between airports and Birmingham when it's dark.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you edit your question to be a little more specific as to what it is you're trying to do where and when?  As it stands your question looks more like a rant.

Comment: 'better' is subjective, so I've edited your question to make it more structured and just to ask for objective alternatives.  Have added an answer as well, hope that helps.

Comment: Have you considered taking a train? Usually a lot more comfortable than a bus, and when booked in advance can be quite good value too.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Usually we travel too early or too late for trains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few other companies in the UK, although none are particularly great - it's not huge distances so they go for packing you in, more than anything.

- [Megabus](https://uk.megabus.com/) - if you get tickets well in advance, they can be incredibly cheap. They also have a sleeper service from London to Glasgow/Edinburgh.
- [Eurolines](https://www.eurolines.de/de/startseite/) - although as they're an associate company of National Express you may not like them - but they run coach services to / from London with various cities in Northern Ireland, Ireland and continental Europe. Advance ticketing is required

*Bonus* - [EasyBus](https://www.easybus.com/) - although only in London at present, if you get it in advance, tickets can be very cheap to the airports, from as little as two pounds.

Comment: There are also some other companies who operate long distance coaches, but only for one region. The Oxford Bus Company have excellent buses - wifi, power, decent legroom etc - but that only helps between Oxford and London, Heathrow and Gatwick...

Comment: [Stagecoach Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagecoach_Gold) claim to provide a higher standard of travel: *Stagecoach Gold is a luxury bus service available at no extra cost.*

Answer (score 6):

Another altenative maybe to consider the train, if of course you can find a cheap ticket or one that is similar to the price you would pay on either National Express or the other companies mentioned in Mark's answer.

[Cheap train tickets](http://www.cheaptraintickets.info/) is a resource zone for finding cheaper train tickets. It's packed with hidden tips and tricks for cheap rail fares.

Comment: Usually we travel too early or too late for trains.

Comment: @cja Ah shame, might be helpful for future use however.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to figure out one's coach travel options in Britain is to try [Traveline](http://www.traveline.info/) (on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveline)) journey planner:

> We’re a partnership of transport companies, local authorities and
>   passenger groups which have come together to bring you routes and
>   times for all travel in Great Britain by bus, rail, coach and ferry.

To get the coach services only deselect everything but `coach` in the travel mode settings:

[image]

This will show in the search results who the particular route is serviced by, for example, the route from Tiverton to London (Hammersmith) is serviced by [Berry's Coaches](http://www.berryscoaches.co.uk/):

[image]

You can then search for that name on the Internet and see who runs it and on what other routes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one more, serving the Birmingham area which you seem to be interested in:

[Thandi Express](http://thandiexpress.com/Default.aspx)

> Thandi Express runs daily scheduled services between the following towns - Wolverhampton, Birmingham, Coventry, Luton, Barking/Illford, East Ham/Stratford/Manor Park (East London), Woolwich, Charlton, Dartford, Gravesend/Rochester/Strood/Gillingham (Kent) , Southall, Slough (West London), Leicester, Nottingham/Derby, Sheffield, Bradford/Leeds/Huddersfield/Dewsbury.